# Can anyone tell me why this program runs?

Tags: c

New to  c programming. Here is a question from an assignment. Can anyone tell me why this code still outputs two columns 5 and 2 even though i is less than j.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0, j = 5;
    for (i > j; i + j == 5; j < 2) {
        printf("Two columns\n");
        i = 5;
        j = 2;
    }
    printf("    %d     %d\n", i, j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even though what

Comment: You are using wrong for loop so it run for one iteration because j > 2 true for first time that's why its return 5 and 2. .

Comment: I think you are confused by the `i > j` part. It looks like the loop should not start because `i` is less than `j`.

Comment: you're setting the values in the loop, and you're failing the condition at the next iteration.

Comment: this code is broken...

Comment: The compiler issues warnings about `>` and `<` both having no effect. But the variables are initialised, and the continuation condition is good, so the loop iterates once.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, you should only care about the loops condition i.e `i +j ==5`

Comment: The `for` loop is deceptive.  The first and last parts of it (the initial code and the step code) serve no purpose whatsoever.  It is equivalent to `while (i+j == 5)`

Comment: @salman khan where did `j > 2` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the steps executed in order:

- `int i = 0, j = 5;`  local variables `i` and `j` are defined and initialized to `0` and `5` respectively
- `for (i > j; i + j == 5; j < 2) {`:

  - first executes the initial expression `i > j` which evaluates to false (0) and has no side effect, the result is ignored, hence probably completely omitted by the compiler.
  - second executes the test expression `i + j == 5` which evaluates to true (1) so the body of the `for` loop executes.
  - `printf("Two columns\n");` outputs `Two columns` and a newline.
  - `i = 5;` sets `i` to 5.
  - `j = 2;` sets `j` to 2.
  - `}` the increment expression is then evaluated: `j < 2`, which evaluates to false but has no side effect, the result is ignored.
  - the loop then evaluates the test expression again: `i + j == 5` which now evaluates to false (0) since `5 + 2` is different from `5`.
  - the loop exits.
- `printf("    %d     %d\n", i, j);` outputs the numbers `5` and `2` and a newline as you observe.
- `return 0;` `main` returns the value `0` which is a successful exit status.

This code is very silly and purposely misleading as it has test expressions in all 3 parts of the `for` statement header. Only the middle one is the test expression, the first and last expressions are only used for side effects, such as initializing and incrementing a loop counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i > j; i + j == 5; j < 2)
```

- In for loop initialization part `i > j` no make sense
- Then `i + j == 5` condition become `true` and executed for loop body where assigned new values to `i` and `j` respectively `5` and `2`.
- Then control goes to for loop increment part where  `j < 2` become `false`. this is also no make sense.
- Then again control goes to condition part where `i+j == 5` becomes false because i is a 5 and and j is a 2. So, `7 == 5` becomes false.

So, output of your code is 5 and 2.